# My code should each the value of the $age variable, but instead it echoes the word "age"?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
// Set the MySQL Configuration
$db_host       = "";
$db_user       = "";
$db_password   = "";
$db_name       = "";
$db_table      = "";

// Start Connection
$db_connect        =  mysql_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);

// Select Database
$db_select        =  mysql_select_db ($db_name, $db_connect);

// Update Values in Database


$query         = "UPDATE $db_table SET

    age  =  age + 1,

    land = '".$_POST['data3']."'

    WHERE name = '".$_POST['data1']."'

    ";


// Execution MySQL query        
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db_connect));

//Close MySQL connection
mysql_close($db_connect);

//HTTP Response
echo " your age: age";

?>
```

I want to echo the value of the `$age` variable, but instead I always get the word "age." For example, the code should echo `your age: 5` but instead it outputs `your age: age`

Comment: Why would it echo anything else but that? You're just printing a string...

Comment: You have executed an `UPDATE` query, but that will not return any values back to your script. If you want to retrieve the row you updated, you will need to execute another query as a `SELECT` statement and fetch the row from it.

Comment: Note also that your script is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. At a minimum, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your `$_POST` inputs to the query.  `name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data1']) . "'`

Comment: @Michael I couldn't agree more. See my answer for more detailed information about prepared statements and the options available to use them in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to run a `SELECT` query to retrieve the updated value of `age`. The query should look something like this:

```
"SELECT age FROM db_table_name WHERE name = ?"
```

Once you've obtained the result of that query, with say `PDO::fetch` (see my note below about PDO) and set it to the variable `$age`, you can output it with an echo statement:

```
echo "Your age: $age";
```

Also, please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

The reason I'm not giving you the exact code for this is because it shouldn't be done with the `mysql_*` functions *at all*. Creating an SQL query with data directly from `$_POST` like this is *extremely dangerous code to use and an incredibly bad idea all around. Never do this.* You open yourself up to numerous SQL injection attacks. Even using `mysql_real_escape_string` is not enough. You should be using prepared statements.

UPDATE: Here is a simple example that's close to what you're asking, but using PDO and prepared statements. This is by no means a comprehensive example, since there are several ways to alter it that will still work (e.g. prepared statements allow you to execute multiple statements on the server in one statement), and I don't have a working server at the moment to test to make sure it's *exactly* what you need, but I hope it gets the point of across.

```
<?php

// Create the database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

// Set PDO/MySQL to use real prepared statements instead of emulating them
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// The UPDATE query we're going to use
$update_query = "UPDATE `db_table_name` SET age = age + 1, land = :land WHERE name = :name";

// Prepare the query
$stmt = $db->prepare($update_query);

// Bind variables to the named parameters in the query with their values from $_POST
$land = $_POST['data3'];
$name = $_POST['data1']
$stmt->bindParam(':land', $land);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);

// Execute the statement on the server
$stmt->execute();

// The SELECT query we're going to use
$select_query = "SELECT age FROM `db_table_name` WHERE name = :name";

// Again, prepare the query
$stmt_select = $db->prepare($select_query);

// Bind the paramters (in this case only one) to the new statement
// $name is already set from before, so there is no need to set it again
$stmt_select->bindParam(":name", $name);

$stmt_select->execute();

/*
 * With no arguments, PDO::fetchColumn() returns the first column
 * in the current row of the result set. Otherwise, fetchColumn()
 * takes a 0-indexed number of the column you wish to retrieve
 * from the row.
*/
$age = $stmt_select->fetchColumn();

echo("Your age: $age");
?>
```

All of this information came directly from the PHP documentation on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO::fetchColumn()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Comment: @chris If this answer was helpful, please click the green checkmark next to it (underneath the voting) to accept it. The more people who see answers cautioning against the `mysql_*` functions, the better, in my opinion.